# Special characters in bound knockout data model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, special-characters

I have a data model with special characters in it (degree signs).. so the property contains the following: "48 `&deg;` f". However, when the UI updates to this data, I see the "`&deg;`", not the degree sign. I have also tried "`&#176;`", but that doesn't work either.

How do I put special characters in the data model and have them appear on the UI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `html` binding for this:

```
<span data-bind="html: test"></span>

var vm = {
    test: ko.observable("48 &deg; f")
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svu82/

Read more in the KO documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html

Comment: There is a bigger problem though with this. Add the following to the fiddle and try to change the binding to an html binding.  <textarea data-bind="value: test"></textarea>. Then try to render the encoded character properly. Good Luck! When the value binding is used the character is encoded, when html is used the value doesn't update when changed. Also, the value binding breaks the html code when value binding is used with some characters(eg. quotations and newlines).

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think saving the data encoded in the database is a good idea.**

Using ASPNET/MVC C# (with Razor) to bind information from the database to a value of text area. I am using c# and had to do something like this server-side while setting the observable.

**Example of replaced charcters so value binding works properly.**

```
model.Description  = ko.observable(
   @html.Raw(
             Model.Description.Replace("\"", "\\\"")
                .Replace("'", "\\\'")
                .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\r\\n")
            )
);
```

**An extension method makes the binding nicer.**

```
    public static IHtmlString HtmlEscape(this String str)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return new HtmlString("");
        var html = ((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)
                       WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html;

        return html.Raw(
             str.Replace("\"", "\\\"")
                .Replace("'", "\\\'")
                .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\r\\n"));
    }
```

**And the binding**

```
Description: ko.observable("@(Model.Description.HtmlEscape())");
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The string is not encoded in the database. It is transferred to the client over a JSONP request, so it has to be encoded on the server prior to the transfer. There is no need for me to add an extra function to remove the encoding when the html binding does this in one step.